# How to obtain user input from perl script running in apache web server?

Tags: apache, perl, cgi

I have a raspberry pi running the latest Raspbian image with apache2 installed. I have a perl script in my /usr/lib/cgi-bin directory that I am using on a local, ad-hoc network without internet access.

Here is my perl file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
$config=`cat /home/pi/Desktop/AutoPi/AutoPi.config`;
print <<"EOF";
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Hello, world!</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Hello, world!</H1>
<br><br>
</BODY>
</HTML>
EOF
```

This works great, and I can use perl system commands, like:

```
$my_dir=`pwd`;
```

...and pass them to the webpage that the user sees. This is great. However, I need to be able to have the user click a button and execute code as well.

I am comfortable using perl, and want to keep everything in the perl file if possible. If I can just program a simple button that, upon being pressed, can execute a simple command server side, I can do the rest.

Comment: Can you create a form that `POST`s to your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a script to get you started using CGI.pm to access parameters from the submitted form.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw(escapeHTML);
#use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $q = CGI->new;

my $text = $q->param('text') || '';

print $q->header('text/html; charset=utf-8');

my $safe_text = escapeHTML($text);

print <<"EOF";
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <div>$safe_text</div>

  <form method="post">
    <textarea name="text" rows="5" cols="40">$safe_text</textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
EOF
```

CGI.pm is not really a recommended way to build a web application but it sounds like you're having fun so go for it.  Try removing the '#' on the `use CGI::Carp` line.  If the script still runs then leave it that way so you'll get some error messages in the browser.  You'll also want to run this command to look for errors:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Comment: That is fantastic, thanks a lot. This is exactly what I needed!